# How to compare two objects (the calling object and the parameter) in a class?

Tags: c++, oop, class, compare

I am writing a "Date" class for an assignment and I am having trouble doing one the of the functions.

This is the header file for the class.

```
class Date
{
public:
Date();                                  // Constructor without parameters
Date(int m, int d, int y); // Constructor with parameters.

// accessors
int GetMonth();               // returns the size of the diamond
int GetDay();
int GetYear();

// mutators
bool Set(int m, int d, int y);
bool SetFormat(char f);

// standard input and output routines
void Input();             
void Show();              
void Increment(int numDays = 1);                 
int Compare(const Date& d);     

private:
int month,                    // month variables
    day,                 // day variable
    year;               // year variable
char format;
};
```

The member function I am trying to make is the int Compare(const Date& d) function. I need this function to compare two Date objects (the calling object and the
parameter), and should return: -1 if the calling object comes first
chronologically, 0 if the objects are the same date, and 1 if the parameter object
comes first chronologically.

I have tried doing a simple if statement with the == operator but I get errors.

```
  if (d1 == d2)
     cout << "The dates are the same";
     return (0);
```

After the objects are created, the function should be called like this d1.Compare(d2)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int Date :: Compare (const Date& d) {

   if (year<d.year) {
      return -1;
   }
   else if (year>d.year) {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (month<d.month) {
      return -1;
   }
   else if (month>d.month) {
      return 1;
   }
   // same for day

   return 0;
}
```

Usually, you'lll also want to provide overloaded comparison operators, for example (also within the class definition):

```
bool operator == (const Date& d) const {
   return !Compare(d);
}

bool operator < (const Date& d) const {
  return Compare(d)<0;   
}

... // consider using boost::operators
```

PS: There are smarter implementations of `Compare()` - just check the other answers. This one is pretty straightforward and readable, but conforms exactly to your specification.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

into the class's `public` area

```
bool operator==(const Date& rhs) const {
    return
       year == rhs.year
       && month == rhs.month
       && day == rhs.day
    ;
}
```

Comment: Notice that the method is const. Your Compare() method (and others) should be const too. If your Compare() would be const I could call it from the operator==() :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I might implement your Compare function, although the format takes a moment to get used to:

```
int Date::Compare(const Date& d) const {
  return
    (year < d.year)   ? -1 :
    (year > d.year)   ?  1 :
    (month < d.month) ? -1 :
    (month > d.month) ?  1 :
    (day < d.day)     ? -1 :
    (day > d.day)     ?  1 :
                         0;
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
template<typename T>
int Compare(T a, T b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (b < a) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int Date::Compare(const Date& d) const {
    int a = Compare(year, d.year);
    if (a == 0) a = Compare(month, d.month);
    if (a == 0) a = Compare(day, d.day);
    return a;
}
```

I wouldn't use `operator==` in Compare, although the answers telling you how to implement `operator==` are fine if you want that as well. The reason is that `operator==` is clearly going to have to look at the same fields compare does, and if it returns false then Compare will do very similar work again. Efficiency probably isn't an issue, but it duplicates the logic.

And for what it's worth, idiomatic C++ is to implement `operator<` and possibly also a consistent `operator==` and `operator>`, rather than an all-in-one Compare function. The operators are what the standard algorithms use for searching and sorting, and everything else follows. Java chose to do things differently.

Answer (score 4):

Compare object *by contents*, i.e. in your case the dates are equal of the day, month and year are equal (and perhaps `format` - depending on your semantics).

Also, C++ already includes a great facility for object comparison: `operator ==` which allows writing clearer code than calling a `Compare` method.

By the way, take care with this:

```
  if (d1 == d2)
     cout << "The dates are the same";
     return (0);
```

If the condition is true, the `cout` line will be executed. The `return` will be executed even if the condition is false.

Answer (score 4):

The semantics of C++'s `||` make this a little cluttered:

```
static inline int cmp(int a, int b)
{
  return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1;
}

int Date::Compare(const Date& d)
{
  int result;
  (result = cmp(year, d.year))     ||
    (result = cmp(month, d.month)) ||
      (result = cmp(day, d.day));

  return result;
}
```

Comment: But if you really must start the name with an underscore, make sure it's not in the global namespace - that's not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use operator== for user-defined types, you must implement it.  In addition, your Compare function should be marked as a const member function:

```
class Date
{
...
int Compare(const Date& d) const;     

bool operator==(const Date& rhs) const
{
    return 0 == Compare(rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do d1 === d2, because I believe it compares the memory addresses (haven't done C++ in a while).

What you need to do is write a function that will compare each member of your Date class and return negative number, 0, or positive number. Negative means lesser, 0 means the same, and positive means greater.

For example, in Java:

```
public int compareTo(Date date) {
  int returnValue = 0;

   returnValue = this.getYear() - date.getYear();

   if(returnValue == 0) {
      returnValue = this.getMonth() - date.getMonth();

      if(returnValue == 0) {
         returnValue = this.getDay() - date.getDay();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: d1 == d2 doesn't compile unless the operation is implemented someplace.  In this case it's not implemented.

Comment: The OP explicitly states "... the function should be called like this d1.Compare(d2)", meaning neither d1 nor d2 are memory addresses (pointers).  Comparison of the memory addresses in this case would entail something like "&d1 == &d2", not "d1 == d2".  Creating an equality operator like the one @Notinlist posted provides the desired d1 == d2 semantics.

Comment: @Void Ah, good point. Like I said, I haven't done C++ in a while. I was in Java-land where everything is a reference/pointer :)

Comment: This implementation of compareTo isn't a good general strategy, because of overflow. Obviously dates aren't going to overflow, so you can get away with it, but consider if `this.getYear()` is INT_MAX and `date.getYear()` is -1. Then LHS > RHS, but LHS - RHS < 0.

Comment: Hopefully there is a validation function that ensures that the year attribute isn't at INT_MAX.

But yes, this probably isn't a generally good strategy.

Comment: Yes, it's fine for dates as long as your dates don't go absurdly far into the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Temp {

public:
       Temp(const char* str) {
         this->str = str;
         printf("Temp [%s] is created\n", this->str);
       }

       ~Temp() {
         printf("Temp [%s] is deleted\n", this->str);
       }

       bool operator == (const Temp& a) const {
         return this->str == a.str;
       }

private:
       const char* str = new char[10];
}

int main() {

   Temp test1{"Hello1"};
   Temp test2{"Hello2"};
   (test1 == test2) ? printf("Equals") : printf("Non equals");

   return 0;
}
```