# operators on Iterators in C++

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, iterator, compiler-errors

I am porting an old code base to OSX.

I have the following snippet of code:

```
FxLayerList::iterator lastVisible = NULL;
for (FxLayerList::iterator iter = mBranch.begin(); iter != mBranch.end(); iter++) {
    if ( (*iter)->IsVisible() && !(*iter)->IsBypass()) {
        lastVisible = iter;
    }
}
if (lastVisible != NULL && (*lastVisible)->GetGeneratedImage()) {
```

I get an error that says: `error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'lastVisible != 0'`

I dont follow, I thought operations like != and ==, etc were standard operations. Why the complaint from the compiler?

UPDATE: I am trying to understand the comparison of objects. What if the code is like this:

```
FxBool FxLayerList::Contains(FxLayer *layer) const
{
for (FxLayerList::const_iterator iter=this->begin(); iter != this->end(); iter++)
{
    if ((*iter) == layer) {
        return true;
    }   
}
return false;
}
```

with errors like: `error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:`

What is the core concept I am missing?

Update 2:

```
// FxSmartPtr is a smart pointer that is also typed for each class, avoiding the need for any casting.
// Setting an FxSmartPtr to NULL actually kills the memory that it's pointing to as well.
template <class eachClass>
class FxSmartPtr
{
public:
// Construction

// Default constructor makes an empty container.
FxSmartPtr(void) : mPtr(NULL) {}

// Construction with a ptr adds one reference to it.
FxSmartPtr(eachClass *ptr) : mPtr(ptr) { this->Reference(); }

// Copy construction means that both smart pointers end up with a reference to the object.
FxSmartPtr(const FxSmartPtr & inPtr) :mPtr(NULL) { FrAssignRef(mPtr,(eachClass *)inPtr.mPtr); }

// Default construction
FxSmartPtr(FxConstructArg cons) { if (cons == FcNew) mPtr = new eachClass(); }
FxSmartPtr(FxConstructArg cons,eachClass *ptr) { if (cons == FcNew) mPtr = ptr; }

// Destructor removes only the one reference that we own.
~FxSmartPtr() { this->Dispose(); }


// Most important and common use is via assignment. References are always safely balanced.

// AssignReference safely replaces one reference counted ptr with another. 
static inline eachClass * FrAssignRef(eachClass *& to, eachClass * from)
    { if (from) from->AddReference(); if (to) to->RemoveReference(); to = from; return to; }

// If you assign a pointer to this object we add one reference count to it.
const FxSmartPtr<eachClass> & operator = (const eachClass *ptr)
    { FrAssignRef(mPtr,(eachClass *)ptr); return *this; }

// Replace our referenced object with a reference added to the incoming one.
const FxSmartPtr<eachClass> & operator = (const FxSmartPtr & inPtr)
    { FrAssignRef(mPtr,(eachClass *)inPtr.mPtr); return *this; }

// Assignment to a dumb pointer takes/gives no references.
operator eachClass * (void) const
    { return mPtr; }
eachClass * operator->(void)
    { if (mPtr != NULL) if (mPtr->GetRefCount() < 1 || mPtr->GetRefCount() > 10000) ASSERT(0); return mPtr; }
const eachClass * operator->(void) const
    { if (mPtr != NULL) if (mPtr->GetRefCount() < 1 || mPtr->GetRefCount() > 10000) ASSERT(0); return mPtr; }


// Explicit assignment and object transfers

// Get() - return ptr with no reference
eachClass * Get(void) const
    { return mPtr; }
eachClass * GetPtr(void)
    { return mPtr; }

// Own() - return ownership with ptr
eachClass * Own(void)
    { if (mPtr) mPtr->AddReference(); return mPtr; }

// Set() - we take our own reference on your object
FxSmartPtr<eachClass> & Set(eachClass * ptr)
    { FrAssignRef(mPtr, ptr); return *this; }

// Take() - you give us your reference
FxSmartPtr<eachClass> & Take(eachClass * ptr)
    { FrDispose(mPtr); mPtr = ptr; return *this; }


// Comparison operators compare the pointers contained in each
FxBool operator == (const FxSmartPtr & inPtr) const
    { return (mPtr == inPtr.mPtr); }
FxBool operator == (const eachClass * inPtr) const
    { return (mPtr == inPtr); }
FxBool operator != (const FxSmartPtr & inPtr) const
    { return (mPtr != inPtr.mPtr); }
FxBool operator != (const eachClass * inPtr) const
    { return (mPtr != inPtr); }

// Reference() and Dispose() change the normal reference count. If you use these then
// you end up having to count references externally.

// Safely take a reference if the ptr is not nil
void Reference(void) { if (mPtr != NULL) mPtr->AddReference(); }
// Safely dispose one reference count.
void Dispose(void) { if (mPtr != NULL)
    // JASON/INDIE - SLACKMOEHRLE@GMAIL.COM
    // { ULONG refs = mPtr->GetRefCount(); mPtr->RemoveReference(); if (refs <= 1) mPtr = NULL; } }
    { FxUInt32 refs = mPtr->GetRefCount(); mPtr->RemoveReference(); if (refs <= 1) mPtr = NULL; } }

protected:

    eachClass *mPtr;
};
```

Comment: try something like *lastVisible != NULL

Comment: If FxLayerList is a vector, the iterator might be a plain pointer in some implementations. The proper way is to initialize it and test against end().

Answer (score 4):

It looks that `lastVisible` is an object rather than just a pointer. If you compare some object with something, then it has to have the appropriate operator.

Maybe this would compile?

```
FxLayerList::iterator lastVisible = mBranch.end();
for (FxLayerList::iterator iter = mBranch.begin(); iter != mBranch.end(); iter++)
{
    if ( (*iter)->IsVisible() && !(*iter)->IsBypass())
    {
       lastVisible = iter;
    }
}
if (lastVisible != mBranch.end() && (*lastVisible)->GetGeneratedImage())
{ ...
```

Or if `FxLayerList` is just a collection of pointers to `FxLayer`, this would be more straightforward:

```
FxLayer *lastVisible = NULL;
for (FxLayerList::iterator iter = mBranch.begin(); iter != mBranch.end(); iter++)
{
    if ( (*iter)->IsVisible() && !(*iter)->IsBypass())
    {
        lastVisible = *iter;
    }
}
if (lastVisible != NULL && lastVisible->GetGeneratedImage())
{ ...
```

Answer to **UPDATE**: see my comment below. The problem (compiler error message) can be solved by explicitly retrieving the pointer from the "smart" pointer:

```
FxBool FxLayerList::Contains(FxLayer *layer) const
{
    for (FxLayerList::const_iterator iter=this->begin(); iter != this->end(); iter++)
    {
        if (iter.Get() == layer) {
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The way he call the functions on the objects show that he uses pointers: (*lastVisible)->GetGeneratedImage())

Comment: @Fox32 - Iterators are used like pointers. They are just not null.

Comment: Both * and -> are overloadable, so maybe not.

Comment: @Messa - can you look at my update above? Can you explain the core concept I am missing when comparing objects? I thoughts that operators like ==, !=, >= were standard functionality.

Comment: @ABV C++ knows how to compare numbers, pointers, but does not know anything about objects. The developer has to specify how exactly two objects of some class(es) should be compared.

Comment: @ABV But I think the problem with your code is that we don't know how exactly is `FxLayerList` defined :) Maybe it's a list of smart pointers (instead of just plain pointers)?

Comment: @Messa - It is define: `class FxLayerList : public vector<FxSmartPtr<FxLayer> > {` The developer has comments of `// FxSmartPtr is a smart pointer that is also typed for each class, avoiding the need for any casting.
// Setting an FxSmartPtr to NULL actually kills the memory that it's pointing to as well.`

Comment: I bet that `FxSmartPtr` has a constructor `FxSmartPtr<T>(T*)` that is _not_ marked as `explicit`, right? :)

Comment: @ABV Yes. That is the reason why one-parameter constructors should be `explicit`. In comparison `if ((*iter) == layer)`, where `FxSmartPtr<FxLayer>` is compared with `FxLayer*`, the compiler does not know (cannot decide), whether it should convert `FxSmartPtr<FxLayer>` to `FxLayer*` and then compare two "plain" pointers, or whether it should convert the second pointer to `FxSmartPtr<FxLayer>` and then compare two instances of `FxSmartPtr<FxLayer>`. This is what the compiler wants to tell by that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The standard operators are overloadable to support directly comparing objects, but out of the box they wouldn't know what to compare (I *think* the default behaviour would be to simply compare the object's address, but your error seems to contradict that).

In any event, [How to compare two objects (the calling object and the parameter) in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194762/how-to-compare-two-objects-the-calling-object-and-the-parameter-in-a-class) seems to be a very similar problem.

Within your class you should probably add in something like what Alexander suggested above:

```
int Date :: Compare (const Date& d) {

  if (year<d.year) {
    return -1;
  }
}

bool operator == (const Date& d) const {
   return !Compare(d);
}
```

Of course modified to suit your comparison requirements.