# Full-range comparison operator in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, one can define `bool operator<()` on a class `Foo`, and stdlib algorithms like `next_permutation()` use that to infer ordering.

However, only providing a way to check if one instance of `Foo` is less than another, does not provide the full range of possible comparisons. For example, the instances may be equal.

Is there a standard or protocol for supporting the full range of comparisons in C++?

This question is motivated by the `<=>` "spaceship" operator defined in Ruby, which is a method returning -1, 0, or 1, if the receiver is less than, equal, or larger than the argument, respectively.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194762/how-to-compare-two-objects-the-calling-object-and-the-parameter-in-a-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the C++ standard functions (and classes) that use a less-than comparator do not care whether or not objects are equal. Instead, they use a concept of "equivalence" defined that `x` and `y` are equivalent if and only if `!(x < y) && !(y < x)`. If `x < y` is a strict weak order, then `!(x < y) && !(y < x)` is an equivalence relation.

So no, there is no precise equivalent of the Ruby spaceship because those C++ operations do not accept the trichotomy of less than, equal, or greater than. However, you can quite easily write:

```
template <typename T>
int spaceship(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) {
    if (lhs < rhs) return -1;
    if (rhs < lhs) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm curious: isn't there an efficiency concern with this definition?  It means that if you ever have to check for equivalence, you'll have to call `operator<` twice!  Given that `operator<` is an arbitrarily-defined function, the cost here is arbitrary and can add up, for example in hot loops.

Comment: @DunPeal: generally no efficiency concern, because the `<` comparison is (on average) cheaper than a spaceship comparison to begin with, so it doesn't matter if you do a few more of them. No doubt there are some algorithms that work out faster one way or the other. So for example there are two ways to do a quicksort -- a 2-way partition or a 3-way partition. Using `<` the 3-way partition has to do up to 2 comparisons per element, so for types where `<=>` can be implemented cheaper than two full `<` comparisons (such as `string`) you'd benefit from it.

Comment: @DunPeal: You could though use template specialization to optimize it if the given type support it, such as `std::string` does through the `std::string::compare` member function.

Comment: ... With a binary search, on the other hand, even if `<=>` is available I think it's probably more efficient for most types to use `<` throughout and then one additional comparison at the end, rather than a `<=>` that might do extra work each call to give you more information than you need. I believe the reason for defining things this way, though, is not to do with efficiency but rather to do with making the interface simple. You define one comparator function, or one operator overload, and you're finished. It's then up to the algorithms to use it as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @SteveJessop: how does the C++ stdlib (say, the quicksort algo you mention) know to perform two less-than operations if `operator==` is not defined, but straight `==` if it is?  From what I know of C++, invoking a nonexisting method is just an error, so naively, if an object only defined `operator<`, I'd expect `==` called on it to fail.

Comment: @DunPeal: it doesn't know that. `std::sort` is guaranteed not to call `==`. Like I said at the top of my answer, it does not care whether objects are equal, only whether they are equivalent with respect to `<` (or whatever other comparator you supply to `sort`).

Answer (score 1):

[P0515](https://wg21.link/p0515) adds this (spelled, oddly enough, `<=>`). It should be in C++2x